# Ipa file is not installing on Client's device

Tags: iphone

I have created build file with Development Provisioning , I selected 5 device for that provisioning profile But The Ipa is not installing on client't devices and successfully installed on remaining 4 devices .
Did following things :-

```
I checked device UDID , it is proper. 
Set device restrictions off for installing apps.
Set minimum deployment target to 4.3 and client is having 4.3 ios version iphone
```

Device is showing "Could not install IPA "  and when this alert appears The Ipa file got deselected from iTunes .

Can any one tell be what could  be the possible reasons behind this.

Answer (score 3):

Go To iphone **Settings-->General--->Profiles-->Click Remove...!**

Connect the iphone to mac goto open xcode under menu **windows-->organizer-->Tap to Device**, find the iphone name and click it's shows **use for development** button to click and enter itunes connect username and password and Provisioning installing sucessfully..!

Retry to install ipa file...!

Comment: Client don't have mac :( But thanks for other solution on iphone

Answer (score 0):

Have you send the provisioning profile too, to your customer?
i am sending everytime the provisioning profile with all devices, and also creating the ipa file with that profile.

the customer have to drag and drop the profile and *.ipa file to itunes(doesnt matter if windows or mac).

At first, i have troubles with that, too.
And at the momemt i am using
http://testflightapp.com/ (on the site, everything is explained clearly)

you have to register yourself as developer, upload your binary, sent a invite mail to your customer, he have to register, too. after that his device will be added to your account and you can share updates over the air. he can make updates with **testflightapp**, if you upload a new binary(he will be notified by mail).

i am not sure if this helps you, but for the future you can still save time and have not check 10 times the profiles.